# Time normalize a jump force variable in R

Tags: r, normalization, resampling

I have a dataset that contains the vertical ground reaction force for two vertical jumps provided by one athlete.  This is a continuous variable.  I also have a column that gives the athlete's displacement, which is also a continuous variable.  The data is sampled at 500 Hz for both jumps but jump #1 took more time to perform than jump #2 thus it has a greater number of rows.

I want to normalize the displacement from each jump on a scale from 0 to 100% of the total displacement to get the force variable to equal lengths for both jumps.  I then want to calculate mean force vs. displacement curve average across the jumps.

As the data set is quite long, I've included a shortened example of how the data currently exists, and how I want it to end up looking.  I am hoping someone might be able to provide a good approach for normalizing the displacement on a scale from 0 to 100% and ensuring the number of rows for each jump are the same.

NB: In the code below, I chose to represent a sampling frequency of 10 Hz just to illustrate how the data is set up in a simple manner so that I can get some advice on my approach.

**Current raw data structure:**

```
Jump_Number     Displacement    Force    Time
     1               0           800       0
     1             -0.10         700       0.1
     1             -0.29         500       0.2
     1             -0.40         200       0.3
     1             -0.45         100       0.4
     1             -0.50         500       0.5
     1             -0.30         800       0.6
     1             -0.10         1200      0.7
     1             -0.05         1300      0.8
     1              0.05         1250      0.9
     2               0           800       0.0
     2             -0.10         678       0.1
     2             -0.29         499       0.2
     2             -0.40         178       0.3
     2             -0.45         90        0.4
     2             -0.50         600       0.5
     2             -0.40         810       0.6
     2             -0.35         999       0.7
     2             -0.29         1135      0.8
     2             -0.10         1250      0.9
     2             -0.05         1401      1.0
     2              0.05         1345      1.1
```

**Desired normalized data structure:**

```
  Jump_Number     Normalized_Displacement_(%)  Force    
     1                     0                    800       
     1                    10                    700       
     1                    20                    500       
     1                    30                    200       
     1                    40                    100       
     1                    50                    500       
     1                    60                    800       
     1                    70                    1200      
     1                    80                    1300      
     1                    90                    1289
     1                   100                    1250     
     2                    0                     800       
     2                   10                     678      
     2                   20                     499       
     2                   30                     178       
     2                   40                     90        
     2                   50                     600       
     2                   60                     810       
     2                   70                     999       
     2                   80                     1135      
     2                   90                     1250      
     2                  100                     1345
```

Comment: It is not entirely clear why you call resulting column "normalized displacement" unless values in desired outcome are not matching the example. I would think that normalisation can be done like this: `(Displacement - min) / range * 100 `.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you don't really expect the forces corresponding to the "normalized displacement" to be equal to those for the original displacements.  With that assumption you can use the script below to produce the data you need.

```
require(ggplot2)

# Read the data
jump_names = c("Jump_Number", "Displacement", "Force", "Time")
jump_data = transpose(data.frame(
     c(1, 0, 800, 0),
     c(1, -0.10, 700, 0.1),
     c(1, -0.29, 500, 0.2),
     c(1, -0.40, 200, 0.3),
     c(1, -0.45, 100, 0.4),
     c(1, -0.50, 500, 0.5),
     c(1, -0.30, 800, 0.6),
     c(1, -0.10, 1200, 0.7),
     c(1, -0.05, 1300, 0.8),
     c(1, 0.05, 1250, 0.9),
     c(2, 0, 800, 0.0),
     c(2, -0.10, 678, 0.1),
     c(2, -0.29, 499, 0.2),
     c(2, -0.40, 178, 0.3),
     c(2, -0.45, 90, 0.4),
     c(2, -0.50, 600, 0.5),
     c(2, -0.40, 810, 0.6),
     c(2, -0.35, 999, 0.7),
     c(2, -0.29, 1135, 0.8),
     c(2, -0.10, 1250, 0.9),
     c(2, -0.05, 1401, 1.0),
     c(2, 0.05, 1345, 1.1)))
names(jump_data) =  jump_names
jump_data$Jump_Number = as.factor(jump_data$Jump_Number)

# Compute percent displacement
jump_data$Total_Displacement = ave(abs(jump_data$Displacement), jump_data$Jump_Number, FUN = cumsum)
jump_data$Max_Displacement = ave(abs(jump_data$Total_Displacement), jump_data$Jump_Number, FUN = max)
jump_data$Percent_Displacement = jump_data$Total_Displacement/jump_data$Max_Displacement*100

# Split the data
jump_data_split = split(jump_data, jump_data$Jump_Number)

# Apply interpolation and the combine
interp_data = data.frame()
for (ii in 1:length(jump_data_split)) {
  linear_interp = data.frame(approx(jump_data_split[[ii]]$Percent_Displacement, 
                jump_data_split[[ii]]$Force, 
                xout = seq(0, 100, by = 10), 
                method = "linear"))
  linear_interp$Jump_Number = paste0(ii, "interp")
  interp_data = rbind(interp_data, linear_interp)
}
interp_data$Jump_Number = as.factor(interp_data$Jump_Number)
names(interp_data) = c("Percent_Displacement", "Force", "Jump_Number")

# Plots
plt = ggplot(jump_data,
             aes(x = Time, y = -Displacement, 
                 color = Jump_Number, group = Jump_Number)) +
      geom_path() + 
      theme_bw()
print(plt)
dev.copy(png, "disp_time.png")
dev.off()

dev.new()
plt0 = ggplot(jump_data,
             aes(x = Time, y = Total_Displacement, 
                 color = Jump_Number, group = Jump_Number)) +
      geom_path() + 
      theme_bw()
print(plt0)
dev.copy(png, "tot_disp_time.png")
dev.off()

dev.new()
plt1 = ggplot(jump_data,
             aes(x = Time, y = Force, 
                 color = Jump_Number, group = Jump_Number)) +
      geom_path() + 
      theme_bw()
print(plt1)
dev.copy(png, "force_time.png")
dev.off()

dev.new()
plt2 = ggplot()+
         geom_path(data = jump_data, aes(x = Percent_Displacement, y = Force, 
                 color = Jump_Number, group = Jump_Number)) +
         geom_path(data = interp_data, aes(x = Percent_Displacement, y = Force, 
                 color = Jump_Number, group = Jump_Number)) +
      theme_bw()
print(plt2)
dev.copy(png, "force_percent_disp.png")
dev.off()

names(interp_data) = c("Normalized_Displacement_(%)", "Force", "Jump_Number")
print(interp_data)
```

One of the plots produced by the script is:

[image: percent_displacement_time]